# Same Marker position, Different Rotation and Translation matrices - OpenCV

Tags: opengl, opencv, projection-matrix, rotational-matrices

I'm working on an Augmented Reality marker detection program, using OpenCV and I'm getting **two different rotation and translation values** for the *same marker*.

The 3D model switches between these states automatically without my control, when the camera is slightly moved. Screenshots of the above two situations are added below. I want the Image#1 to be the correct one. How to and where to correct this?

I have followed [How to use an OpenCV rotation and translation vector with OpenGL ES in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712049/how-to-use-an-opencv-rotation-and-translation-vector-with-opengl-es-in-android) to create the Projection Matrix for OpenGL. 
ex:

```
// code to convert rotation, translation vector
glLoadMatrixf(ConvertedProjMatrix);
glColor3f(0,1,1) ;
glutSolidTeapot(50.0f);
```

**Image #1** 
[image]

**Image #2** 
[image]

**Additional**

I'd be glad if someone suggests me a way to make the Teapot **sit** on the marker plane. I know I have to edit the Rotation matrix. But what's the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the teapot you can use glRotatef(). If you want to rotate your current matrix for example by 125° around the y-axis you can call:

```
glRotate(125,0,1,0);
```

I can't make out the current orientation of your teapot, but I guess you would need to rotate it by 90° around the x-axis.

I have no idea about your first problem, OpenCV seems unable to decide which of the shown positions is the "correct" one. It depends on what kind of features OpenCV is looking for (edges, high contrast, unique points...) and how you implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swapping the pose algorithm (ITERATIVE, EPNP, P3P)?  Or possibly use the values from the previous calculation - remember that it's just giving you its 'best guess'.